# Flutter: Google and Firebase login not working in production

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-dependencies

I use google_sign_in and firebase_auth. This works fine in simulator and also when compiling an apk and trying directly on a real device but when I publish this to Google Play and I install my app from it, it just doesn't work.

I don't get any error. The login appears and when I click one of my accounts it closes without doing anything.

After getting the credential from Google I login with Firebase to get the real data for that user:

```
Future googleSignIn(BuildContext context,
      [String? email, facebookCredential]) async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount googleUser;
      dynamic popup = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      // cancelled login
      if (popup == null) {
        return null;
      }

      googleUser = popup;

      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      await _firebaseCredential(context, credential);
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }

 _firebaseCredential(BuildContext context, credential) async {
      User user =
          (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)).user!;
      await firebaseProfile.updateUserData(user);
     // from here I do some Firebase changes but Google, Facebook, Apple and email login 
}
```

All setup (including the required permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`) is ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding, **I feel this is due to the SHA fingerprints that need to be included in the Firebase Console is missing for Play Store build.**

During the development we will be probably adding the [SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) of debug.keystore in the Firebase Console.

> And we need to keep in mind that, during the release build you also
> want to [add the fingerprints](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en) of release keystore to the Firebase
> Console (same like of debug).

I don't know whether you have tried the release build in the real devices before pushing to Play Stores. But this may be the reason.

And also note that, if you opted of [Google Play Signing process](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdescriptions-of-keys-artifacts-and-tools%2Capp-signing-process), you should also include the SHA fingerprints of Google Certificate/Keystore from Google developer console of your application. This [link](https://publishingfirstandroidapp.blogspot.com/2017/07/google-play-app-signing-how-to-get.html) will help you to get the fingerprints from Play Store console.

*NOTE : Make sure you have updated google-services.json included in the project*

Hope this helps you or let me know if you are facing something else.

Comment: that makes perfect sense. Let me deploy again with the updated google-services imported

Answer (score 0):

This could be, because you don't added permission for internet on android. In debug mode it's automatically enabled but in release mode not.

You have to add the following lines in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: good point, but it's there. As mentioned it works fine on same phone when generating the apk